# Chrome 62.0.3202.75 no longer applies CSS based on dynamically added attribute with :hover class

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

We have a page that uses jQuery to toggle the values of an attribute named 'show' on  element(s) on the page between 'on' and 'off'.

We have a CSS selector to match the attribute when the value is 'on' with the ':hover' pseudo-class, e.g.;

```
.shiftTable[hover="on"]:hover {background-color: red; font-weight: bold;}
```

The intent is to control when a hover is applied to the element.

This code has been in production for a while (since before I stared ~2 years ago.) IT was working on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE and Edge.

As of Chrome 62.0.3202.75 we noticed internally that the hover effect was not being applied. I read the release notes and didn't see anything I could connect directly to our issue. We have since verified the issue also occurs in Chrome 62.0.3202.94. Firefox and IE continue to function as expected.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dexqzoxd/3/) that reproduces what we are seeing.

In new Chrome, clicking the 'hover on' button an mousing over the 'Some Markup' text inside the target  does nothing. In e.g. Firefox, the same action results in the hover style getting applied to the element.

Interestingly, if I enable the :hover selector in Chrome Dev Tools, hovering starts working as expected, even after disabling the selector again.

Things I've tried:

- Renaming the 'hover' attribute to 'data-hover' - it's my understanding that custom attributed are supposed to be prefixed with 'data-', and I thought Chrome might have started strictly enforcing this.
- Creating a .hover:hover class and using jQuery's addClass method to add the .hover class to the element.

I'm fully willing to believe we're doing something wrong, but I'm unclear on what that might be.

**Edit:** I'm able to verify that forcing reflow solves my problem, but is also very expensive. Now that I have some idea of what the problem is, I've been able to find other similar issues on SO and elsewhere. The solutions all appear to be hacks of various types - adding and removing an empty element, changing opacity or visibility, etc.

To adjust the focus of my question a little, is there a better (more compatible/standards compliant) way to accomplish this same effect without having to 'trick' Chrome into noticing changes changes by making unrelated changes?

Comment: This has to do with rendering optimization. You should force a UI repainting e.g using `$('.shiftTable').attr("hover", "on").hide().show(0)`

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff. Having that detail, I have been able to find dozens of other related issues in SO and elsewhere with various hacks to force Chrome to pay attention to changes. I appended the .hide().show(0) in a jquery method, and verified it solves the problem. It also throws "[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took XXXms" in the dev console every time, probably because the page can have hundreds to thousands of these elements.